# Sending notifications for website users signed via Facebook or Twitter. How?

Tags: e-commerce, registration

Let's imagine that we have ecommerce website that suggests 3 way for user registration:

- regular email
- via facebook
- via twitter

Now let's imagine that we have user signed via facebook/twitter account and we need send him notification about his order (order complete or s/t like that). How can we do this? It is absolutely clear for regular email users - we should just email them notification, but what about Facebook/Twitter users?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Facebook when they authenticate with your application, you can request email permissions to be able to access the email address they have nominated to use with their facebook account. At the point of registeration you could then store this address in your database and all order flow could follow the existing email path.

You could probably re-use this methodology for twitter too.

I can understand the need to differentiate on registration processes however I think you want to streamline post order notification as much as possible for consistency across users.

Comment: It's a pity, but Twitter doesn't provide user email address (see http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=353#c57 ). But as I figured out, it is possible to send notifications directly to user's twitter. I suppose it will be enough, eh?